# помогите исправить код так, чтобы после каждого ввода выводил результат, а потом опять срабатывал prompt пока не нажмут отмену

Tags: javascript

```
var res;

function Calculator(){
    while(true) {
        var question = prompt('введите выражение: ', ' ');
        if (question == null) {
            break;
        }else if(question == 0){
            alert('введены некоректные данные');
        }

        var methods = {
            '-': function(a, b){
                return a - b;
            },
            '+': function(a, b){
                return a + b;
            },
            '/': function(a, b){
                return a / b;
            },
            '*': function(a, b){
                return a * b;
            },
            '**': function(a, b){
                return Math.pow(a, b);
            }
        };

        res = question;

        this.calculate = function(str){
            var split = str.split(' '),
                    a = +split[0],
                    op = split[1],
                    b = +split[2];

            if (!methods[op] || isNaN(a) || isNaN(b)) {
                return NaN;
            }
            alert(methods[op](+a, +b));
        }
    }
}

var calc = new Calculator();
```

var result = calc.calculate(res);
    result();

Comment: А разве оно у вас вообще работает, хотя бы без цикла?

Comment: да, а почему сомнения?

Comment: банально не проходит копипаст https://jsfiddle.net/6tz075fm/

Comment: я новинок в программировании, объясни что такое копипаст

Comment: Причем тут программирование? Копировать-вставить обычно так называют

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю на сколько рабочий у вас код ибо скопировав его и вставив себе и попробовав его - ничего не работает.

А вообще цикл нужно вставлять не в классе, а уже вне его. И как-то это цикл контролировать на всякий случай.

Я немного сделал на свой лад, в результате есть метод, который вызывается в цикле `hasInput()`. Если он возвращает `false`, то все заканчивается, если `true`, то ведет подсчет того, что было введено. Данные сохраняются в поле класса. Ибо если есть класс, то какой смысл то, что ввели внутри класса класть во внешнюю переменную?

Можно еще модифицировать по всякому.
Но основная идея сводится скорее к тому, что цикл должен быть в данном случае во внешней части, а в классе какой либо флаг, который может его прервать.

```js
function Calculator() {
  this.expression = null;

  this.hasInput = function() {
    return this.init();
  };

  this.init = function() {
    this.expression = prompt('введите выражение: ', ' ');
    if (this.expression == null) {
      return false;
    } else if (this.expression == 0) {
      alert('введены некоректные данные');
    }
    return true;
  };

  this.methods = {
    '-': function(a, b) {
      return a - b;
    },
    '+': function(a, b) {
      return a + b;
    },
    '/': function(a, b) {
      return a / b;
    },
    '*': function(a, b) {
      return a * b;
    },
    '**': function(a, b) {
      return Math.pow(a, b);
    }
  };

  this.calculate = function() {
    var split = this.expression.split(' '),
      a = +split[0],
      op = split[1],
      b = +split[2];

    if (!this.methods[op] || isNaN(a) || isNaN(b)) {
      return NaN;
    }
    alert(this.methods[op](+a, +b));
  }
}

var calc = new Calculator();

while (calc.hasInput()) {
  calc.calculate();
}
```